# Why won't my car start? (Starter has recently been replaced)

Tags: battery, ignition, starter

I should preface this post by saying my car has had issues starting for at least a few months now. It is a 1996 Nissan Maxima and it has well over 100,000 miles on it.

I have had very little problems with it (*other than a few maintenance things*) until now. For a few months now, about a half of the time my car will either make sounds like the engine is trying to turn over but struggling, or it is completely silent. Other times, it starts up no problem.

However, yesterday evening I went to start it and it was completely silent. I tried again and again and nothing. The lights on my dash came on and my car would start beeping because the door was open and my seat belt wasn't on, however it was completely silent when I turned the key.

The next day I called AAA, and when they arrived my car immediately started up without AAA having done anything. He did a check on my battery and my starter and he said everything was normal, other than my battery being a bit low. He was adamant that I didn't have to replace my battery right away. In his words, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it." He asked me to drive my car around to run up a charge, which I did. But then later that night when I went to start my car, it did the same thing as before- absolutely silent.

My starter is brand new, recently replaced about a month ago..

Any ideas??

Comment: Maybe a loose wire somewhere, keeping the starter from engaging? Starter Relay going bad?

Comment: A broken cable?

Comment: in addition to the comments above, I'll add: check the battery terminals - make sure the connection is tight and there's no corrosion; also the ignition switch could be faulty.

Comment: Put a battery in it if it is over 3 years old.